# How to test an iOS Facebook app before getting an app ID from Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-apps

I'm developing an iPhone app which uses Facebook sharing. I cannot create the Facebook app because it requires an "iPhone app store ID". I don't have this id because I haven't submitted the app yet. I can't submit the app because it doesn't work yet... because the Facebook integration isn't set up.

It seems that I'm stuck in a paradox! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate an Apple ID for your app, by logging into iTunesConnect and going through the submission process. Just stop short of clicking the 'Ready to Upload' button. Then your app will have an Apple ID that you can use, and you can still go back and change any of the metadata that Apple asked you to enter (description, keywords, screen shots, etc.).

Once you've finished building your app, log back into iTunesConnect, make the final changes to your App Store details, then upload the binary.

Comment: I tried this but I got the following error from Facebook when trying to create the app:


Error
Your iPhone App Store ID is invalid because the iTunes App Store reports your app as being unavailable for iPhone and iPod touch.

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to create the app. Now I'm just holding my breath while the "changes propagate to all servers"

Comment: I'm not sure that this solves the problem. When entering the app ID into the Facebook app settings, Facebook will not detect this app before it's live.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need YOUR Appstore ID, you just need ANY. This ID is used for a link from facebook to your App in the store. As long as you don't care that this link will leed to another app - not yours - i.e. while testing, you can just enter any Appstore ID. That's what I did and it works fine.

[Facebook's iOS tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) says:

> iPhone App Store ID - If you have an iPhone app that is listed in the
>   iTunes App Store enter the ID here, e.g. 123456. If Facebook links out
>   to your app and finds that the user does not have your app installed,
>   then it will take the user to your app in the store. The user can then
>   install your app. If your app is not in the iTunes App Store you can
>   enter any valid app's ID but be sure to update this when your app is
>   approved in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

For testing use **0(Zero)**,

- iPhone Store ID = 0
- iPad Store ID   = 0

and click on **Save Changes**.

**0** Will be disappeared but your work will be done.

Note:- update this id before going live.